# jquery toggle with loading span

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of items with class dof that are shown and hidden with jquery toggle

I am currently using this code to show and hide it:

```
$('.dof').toggle();
```

which works great, but takes about 30 seconds to do the toggle.

I added this to show a loading image:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#loading').show();$('.dof').toggle();$('#loading').hide();">
    Toggle DOF
</a>

<span id="loading" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" />
</span>
```

This isn't showing the loading span.  I can confirm that the loading image shows if I take out the display:none;

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried this from the suggestion of Josiah Ruddell

(forgive me I use coffescript, so I converted it all to coffescript then back for display here)

```
$('#toggledof').click(function() {
  var $dofs, doflen, toggleComplete;
  $("#loading").show();
  toggleComplete = function() {
    return $("#loading").hide();
  };
  $dofs = $(".dof");
  doflen = $dofs.length;
  return $dofs.each(function(i) {
    $(this).toggle();
    if (i === doflen - 1) {
      return toggleComplete();
    }
  });
});
```

Then I changed the a tag to this:

```
<a href="#" id="toggledof">
    Toggle DOF
</a>
```

Comment: When you say takes 30 seconds are you talking about a 30 second animation, or that there are so many elements on the page that it takes 30 seconds to hide them all?

Comment: 30 seconds to hide / show them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with this code, I guess `.toggle()` sucks when you are dealing with 1900 elements....

the html

```
<div id="testdof" style="display:none"></div> <!-- because the dof elements are hidden at page load -->
```

then the jquery

```
$('#toggledof').click(function() {
  if ($('#testdof').css('display') === 'none') {
    $(".dof").show();
    $("#testdof").show();
  } else {
    $(".dof").hide();
    $("#testdof").hide();
  }
});
```

This runs fast enough to not care about a loading element.

Answer (score 0):

The toggle function is not synchronous due to the animation duration option. You can specify a callback for the toggle.

```
$('.dof').toggle(function(){
    $('#loading').hide();
});
```

However, if there are multiple `.dof` elements on the page, the callback will happen for each one.

**Update**
You will want to keep track of where you are in the toggle progress. After all the items have been toggled, show the loader. As an aside, you may consider optimizing the selector to increase the speed of this operation. At the least you can add a node name before the `.` e.g. `div.dof`.

```
var toggleComplete = function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
    },
    $dofs = $('.dof'),
    doflen = $dofs.length;

$dofs.each(function(i){
    $(this).toggle();
    if(i == doflen -1) toggleComplete();
});
```

Comment: I will add the code above that I tried, but still could not get it to show the loading span.

Comment: I don't think hiding that span at the end is even an issue, it seems to do that fine, it is getting it to show before it runs the toggle.

Comment: also, I have td.dof and th.dof fields. I tried adding them to the a onclick that I had in the beginning, and it was just as slow.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the speed of toggle, you can use the overloaded function:

```
$(selector).toggle(speed);
```

where the speed parameter can take the following values: "slow", "fast", "normal", or time in milliseconds.

This will make your animation as per the speed you desire.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify good enough, it takes 30 seconds to hide or show them, I am not trying to set the speed.  I am trying to show a loading image while it is processing.